# Populating a ListBox from database

Tags: c#, wpf, database, entity-framework, listbox

I am using **Entity Framework** to retrieve records from the database. My user control page crashes every time I run it, but after I comment out the lines in BindLstBox method; my user control page runs well. Is there anything wrong with this code? *(DAOActivity is a class file which have CRUD codes in it. I suppose there is nothing wrong there.)* It shows this error when i try to run :

> 'The invocation of the constructor on type 'iStellar.home' that
>   matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line
>   number '5' and line position '14'.

Heres the screenshot of the error :

[image]

```
DAO.DAOActivity daoActivity = new DAO.DAOActivity();

public home()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindListBox();
}

public void BindListBox()
{
    listBox1.ItemsSource = daoActivity.GetAll();
    listBox1.DisplayMemberPath = "ActivityName";
    listBox1.SelectedValuePath = "ActivityID";           
}
```

My XAML :

```
  <ListBox Height="534" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="218,415,0,0"
           Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="512" />
```

Comment: Yes but i've got no idea what the error means ... Btw i am doing this on a user control page.

Comment: What is iSteller.home?

Comment: iStellar.home is the namespace , iStellar is the name of the project , home is the name of my usercontrol page which is home.xaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
         DispatcherPriority.Background,
            new Action(() =>
            {
                listBox1.ItemsSource = daoActivity.GetAll();
                listBox1.DisplayMemberPath = "ActivityName";
                listBox1.SelectedValuePath = "ActivityID";
            }));
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: hi there , thanks for the effort , but it still crash , is it because i am doing in on a usercontrol page? because in mainwindow , i'll can do it in Window_loaded()

Comment: Sorry i don't get what u meant . pardon me for being a newbie here

Comment: Debug the code . Put BreakPoint on BindListBox method and do F10 F10, When the Exception Will Come click ViewDetails and then InnerException.

Comment: No source available , no symbols are loaded for any call stack frame. The source code cannot be displayed

Comment: {"The underlying provider failed on Open."}

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32917/discussion-between-ethicallogics-and-user2376998)